# How to efficiently implement "point-on-heightmap" picking in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, gpu, projective-geometry, ray-picking

I want to track the mouse coordinates in my OpenGL scene on the ground surface of the world which is modeled as a height map. Currently there is no fancy stuff like hardware tessellation. Note that this question is **not** about *object* picking.

Currently I'm doing the following which is clearly dropping the performance because of a read-back operation:

- Render the world (the ground surface)
- *Read back the depth value at the mouse coordinates*
- Render the rest of the scene
- Swap buffers and render the next frame

The read back is between the two render steps because I want the depth value of the ground surface without any objects in front of it. It is done using the following command:

```
GLfloat depth;
glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &depth);
```

My application limits the frame rate to 60 frames per second. When rendering the scene without the read back operation, I experience a CPU usage of less than 5%, but when doing the read back, it increases to about 75% although I'm not doing much to render the scene or update any game model or such things.

A temporary solution is to cache the depth value of the pixel under the mouse and update it only every 5th or 10th frame which causes the CPU usage going back down below 10%. But clearly can't be the best solution to the problem.

How can I implement picking (**not object picking** since I want the (floating point) coordinates on the surface) efficiently?

I already thought of reading back the depth value of the front buffer instead of the back buffer, but when googling on how to do so, I only find people complaining about glRead* methods to be best avoided at all. But how can I *read something* (do picking) without *reading something* (using glRead*)?

I'm confused. How do other people implement picking?

---

A totally different approach would be implementing the world surface picking in software. It should be no big deal to reconstruct a 3D ray from the camera "into the depth", representing the points in space which are rendered at the target pixel. Then I could implement an intersection algorithm to find the front-most point on the surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You typically implement it on the CPU! Find your picking ray in heightmap coordinates and do a simple line-trace across the heightmap. This is very similar to line-drawing. In each cell you intersect, test against the triangles you used to triangulate it.

It is important to avoid reading from the GPU until it's done. Since you normally schedule drawing commands several frames ahead (GL does this automatically), this means that you will also only get the results then - or stall the CPU until the GPU caught up. But don't do that for simple things like this!

Comment: When this idea first came into my mind, it just sounded "the wrong way". But when reading more and more about GPU performance, especially taking the command queue into account, doing it on the CPU really sounds like "the correct way". Someone else confirming this is really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: However, is it possible to efficiently read the depth buffer which currently is in the GPU rather than the value which will be there when the commands currently being in the queue are executed? Working with an old depth value really is also a solution, if this is not too old.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Or more precisely, you can schedule reads ahead of time and check when they are done. Read up on sync and pixel-buffer-objects

Comment: I thought PBOs are deprecated?

Comment: Where'd you hear that? I don't think they are. You just don't use them to "pre-transform" data anymore, where you get transform feedback now.

Comment: Okay, maybe it was in a concrete context where one doesn't use them anymore. Thank you so far, I want try both suggestions, the PBO based read back being the first one, as I want to do the object picking (which I need additionally) using the same mechanics. And depth reading seems to be the most generic solution to whatever-picking. But if I understand it correctly, I can't read the depth buffer between rendering the world and the objects. So I will end up implementing both.

Comment: @leemes: "*But if I understand it correctly, I can't read the depth buffer between rendering the world and the objects.*" Says who? You can read whatever you want to read, whenever you want to read it. Now, executing such a read likely will induce overhead due to a GPU pipeline flush between the last rendered object pre-read and the read itself. But as long as you're using PBOs, your CPU usage won't increase because of it.